# "Flatten" a 3D Matrix with L2 Norm Reduction

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

I have a `n x m x d` matrix `A` (i.e. `A` is like `d` `n x m` matrices). I would like to convert this into one `n x m` matrix `B` where each element `B(i,j)` is function of `A(i,j,1), ..., A(i,j,d)`, more specifically the L2 norm of these values:

```
B(i,j) = sqrt[A(i,j,1)^2 + ... + A(i,j,d)^2]
```

Meaning I would like to condens or "flatten" the information in matrix `A`. How can I achieve this without resorting to a nested for loop?

Comment: For true vectorization, it would depend on the `function` itself. Share details of the `function`?

Comment: It would be the 2-norm. I updated my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do elementwise squaring and sum along the third dimension to produce a `N x M` matrix and then apply square-root for a vectorized implementation, like so -

```
B = sqrt(sum(A.^2,3))
```

Comment: what do you mean with 'for a vectorized implementation'?

Comment: @fabian789 I meant the listed approach in this answer is a vectorized implementation.

Comment: I had to google that, but it makes sense now. Just starting out with Matlab.